# Cannot write dataframe to a .csv file in python using file.write

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

```
modified_symboltable = open('NYSE_Modified.csv', mode='w')

data1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('NYSE_symbols.csv', sep=',', header='infer', index_col=None, usecols=[0, 1]))

print(data1)

modified_symboltable.write(str(data1))
```

Orignial data 'NYSE_symbols.csv' contains 3144 stock symbol data plus price data. What I want to do here is to isolate only symbols and names and write it to a different file for later use. But I cannot write everything on a 'modified_symboltable.csv', but instead it keeps writing the first 30 and the last 30 data only.
What can I do here? I could not find any solution elsewhere.
Many thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can just create a csv using `data1.to_csv(file.csv)`.

Comment: Thanks.. Realized how noob I am... Such a simple solution there

Comment: Happy to help... we were all once the same. Anyways, feel free to mark my answer accepted when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not call `str(df)`, it returns the `str`ing representation of the data frame, which is by default, the first and last 30 rows.
2. Do not write a dataframe to a file using `file.write`. There are easier ways.

---

Use [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) instead.

```
data1.to_csv('NYSE_Modified.csv')
```